# Multiplication of double values producing unexpected behaviour?

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal, ieee-754

I was writing test cases in which i saw following behaviour. If some one can describe this in layman terms. Adding tag IEEE 754.

70D * 1.1 = 77.0
50D * 1.1 = 55.00000000000001 ?

Comment: ObLink: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html But really, this "issue" with floating point is something you should be able to look up on your own; it’s a multiple-dupe question on SO and all over the web.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 2):

Double value has [precision problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667324/unpredictable-double), you can use `java.math.BigDecimal` to get accurate result:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("50").multiply(new BigDecimal("1.1"))); // 55.00
```

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I tried. On `java version "10.0.1"`, it works fine.

Comment: This one does, because for `valueOf()`, Java uses a roundtrip format. For other values, this is still bound to fail. The inaccuracy introduced by using FP can not always be "corrected" by `valueOf()`.