# Getting wrong answer in double arithmetic in Java

Tags: java, math, floating-point, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double calculation producing odd result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253789/double-calculation-producing-odd-result)

I'm writing a program in Java that deals with a lot of double arithmetic. I eventually get to the point where I need to add 0.6666666666666666 and -0.666666666666667. However, the answer that I get is -3.3306690738754696E-16.

In other words,

```
double d1 = 0.6666666666666666;
double d2 = -0.666666666666667;
System.out.println(d1 + d2);
```

prints out "-3.3306690738754696E-16". Why is this happening?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are limited by the `double` type. It does not store exact decimal fields, but is an IEEE 754 8-byte floating point number.

Comment: You are right, they are similar. Feel free to report the question as a duplicate. Sorry about that.

Comment: See  [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double` values cannot represent all values precisely and this is such an example. You can use `BigDecimal` instead:

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("0.6666666666666666");
BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal("-0.666666666666667");
System.out.println(bd1.add(bd2));
```

Output:

```
-4E-16
```

Comment: Interesting, I always thought of doubles as the ultimate solution for floating-point operations. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @fpele `double` still *is* the ultimate solution for *efficient* floating point on current CPUs. `BigDecimal` is a fixed point type, not floating.

Comment: @us2012:  Are you sure about that?  It looks a lot like floating point to me.  For example, the `scale` of a product is typically the sum of the scales of the multiplicands; with fixed point, I'd expect the result to have the same scale as the inputs.

Comment: @MarkDickinson You're right, I got the terminology mixed up. The point I was trying to make is that `BigDecimal` does not *behave* like we expect floating point numbers to behave. The right term is of course *arbitrary precision*, which comes at a huge performance cost, so that `double` still remains the best solution whenever you don't explicitly need arbitrary precision.

Comment: @us2012: True enough ...

Answer (score 6):

`double`s are not perfectly accurate, and not every decimal can be perfectly represented as a `double` (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_number#Accuracy_problems)). For all practical purposes, `-3.3306690738754696E-16` is `0` *. However, if you need more precision, use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Keep in mind that this alternative will not be nearly as efficient as using primitive `double`s. It's up to you to decide if you need this level of accuracy and to make a choice accordingly.

*: Evidently, that number is not exactly zero, but for the majority of real-world calculations and computations, a value *that* small would be inconsiderable. In meters, this value is smaller than the diameter of protons and neutrons - i.e. very very small. That's what I mean by "for all *practical* purposes".

Comment: Just for educational purposes, could you explain why you say -3.3306690738754696E-16 is 0 for all practical purposes? How can that be? Thank you for your suggestion on BigDecimals

Comment: @fpele: just how big do you think that -3.3306690738754696E-16 is? Have you looked double number representation? Are you familiar with scientific notation? Have you looked up anything at all?

Comment: My bad, I thought the answer was E+16. No need to be rude though.

Comment: @fpele: I'm just amazed, that's all.