# Rounding during a specific situation

Tags: java, formatting, double, rounding, decimalformat

I am attempting to create a calculator app, when I add three doubles together ex. (1.1 + 1.1 + 1.1) 3.3000000000000003 is returned. This only occurs when three numbers are added together (1.1 + 1.1) returns 2.2

**Is their a way to use decimal format to round only if 2 digits in a row are zero to prevent this from happening?**

Thank you!

Please let me know if you need to see more of my code, I think this is sufficient though I may be wrong.

**equals button method**

```
equals_button_IB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //new value being added everytime addition button is pressed, last number to be added will not have addition button
                //pressed after it, so this adds the last value to the values array list
                values.add(current_screen_value);
                System.out.println(values);
                double sum = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i<values.size(); i++){
                    sum+= Double.parseDouble(values.get(i));
                }
                System.out.println(sum);
                clearScreen(null);
                updateScreen(String.valueOf(sum));


            }
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)  I'm suggesting this as a duplicate because it seems likely you need to start solving this problem by learning about floating point approximations.

Comment: As to why this is happening you might want to have a look at this post: [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Comment: @O.Jones The question is similar to mine though the answers only provide an explanation, not a solution

Comment: @vega8 I am looking for a solution, not just an explanation I updated my question to reflect that. I am looking for a way to round in specific situations like when 2 digits in a row are 0.

Comment: Explanations allow you to create your own solutions, @Lontronix, A good one is https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. Another good one for your solution is the normal Java documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html and related, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.util.Locale-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...- and overload, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html It's always good to Read the Fine Manual.

Comment: Excuse me, but `System.out.println` in a GUI?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening probably because of the encoding of [Double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) numbers.
To solve this you can use BigDecimal class (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187997/getting-wrong-answer-in-double-arithmetic-in-java))

Comment: The numbers I am adding together are not very large (1.1 and 2.2) Can you explain why this would be necessary?

Comment: Float and double numbers are stored in a particular way.
You can discover more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)

Please note that BigDecimal is used not only for **big** numbers as we can think, but for **precised** numbers

Comment: Sigh. If computers were motorcycles, the licensing exam would have a couple of questions about how floating point numbers work. They are approximations.

Comment: `BigDecimal` is a sledge hammer to pound a nail here. Perhaps it would be enough simply to format the string representation as desired rather than perform the calculations in perfect precision. Only the OP knows for sure.